# How can I remove every other item from a Sass list?

Tags: sass

Let's say I have a Sass list:

```
$list: 1, red, banana, gold, [class*="test"], potato
```

How might I remove every 1st, 3rd, 5th item etc.? Or alternatively, every 2nd, 4th, 6th item etc? Is this even possible?

I figured you would need to loop through each selector, check if it's index is odd/even, and remove the item as appropriate.

My pseudo-code:

```
@each $item in $list {
    @if $item == nth($list, 2n) {
       $list: remove($list, $item);
    }
}
```

As a non-programer, I am unsure how logical the above sinppet is - assuming of course `remove()` is a valid function, and "2n" represents any even item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nth()` function can only use [specific number](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#nth-instance_method) unlike nth-child in CSS.

One way of working around this is by manually querying the current iteration and appending things that don't match the current number to a new list.

```
$list: 1, red, banana, gold, potato;
$newList: ;
$i: 0;
@each $item in $list {
    $i: $i + 1;
    @if $i == 2 {
        $i: 0;
    }@else{
        $newList: append($newList, $item);
    }
}

@each $item in $newList {
    /* #{$item} */
}
```

[Live Demo](http://sassmeister.com/gist/b3c107414e1dbde46cc8)

Comment: Amazing. Still trying to wrap my head around it, but it does indeed seem to work. For any potential newbies reading, to get this to output only EVEN numbers, change `$i: 0;` to `$i: 1`

Comment: Glad it could help. The process works by creating a counter `$i`, and incrementing it by one each time. Each time it hits a specific number (in this example: 2) it resets the counter, but if the number isn't met it will instead append to the list. It's a bit of a crude alternative but SASS tends to be quite limited in this area at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly late to this party but, there's an alternative to pushing stuff into a new list that might interest you.

Your pseudo code was on the right track theoretically. Essentially simply checking for odd/even values and acting accordingly is achieved with modulo maths - in programming languages using the % symbol.

So using a very vanilla example

```css
$list: 'a','b','c','d','e';
$i: 0;

@each $item in $list {
    $i: $i+1;
    @if $i % 2 == 0
    {
 @debug "it's an even index: " + $item;    
       $list: remove($list, $item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting, that's really great to know, and I think this is probably closer to what I initially had in mind, despite BurpmanJunior's answer working perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Of course should you want to kill odd numbered index items then simply change

`$i % 2 == 0`

to

`$i % 1 == 0`